# how to compare a variable to entries inside an Array

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

Here is my problem.

I'm doing a little weather web app in flash.
So i read an xml feed and copose an array of data from it.

my xml is like this

```
<xml>
<prevision>
<date>22</date>
<hour>5</hour>
<temperature>40</temperature>
</prevision>
<prevision>
<date>22</date>
<hour>10</hour>
<temperature>44</temperature>
</prevision>
<prevision>
<date>22</date>
<hour>14</hour>
<temperature>45</temperature>
</prevision>
<prevision>
<date>22</date>
<hour>20</hour>
<temperature>37</temperature>
</prevision>
</xml>
```

So here is what i'm doing with my Actionscript 2

```
//**************************************
// Here i'm getting the current hour

var mytime = new Date();
var currenthour = mytime.getHours();

//*************************************
// Here i'm getting my XML

var myhour:Array = new Array();
var myxml:XML = new XML();
myxml.ignoreWhite = true;
myxml.onLoad = function(success)
{
dataextractor = myxml.firstChild.childNodes;
for (var j = 0; j < dataextractor.length; j++)
{
myhour.push(dataextractor[j].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
}
// Doing this
trace(mydate);
}
// Will return this
// 5 , 10,  14 , 20
```

Now what i would like to do is to find and trace the entry in mydate array which have a a value that approach the most to "currenthour" variable (which is my current time i'm getting upper).

For exemple if currenthour = 11
In the case that i have myhour array equal to 5 , 10 , 14 , 20
The best match will be myhour[1]

Can someone help to do so?
myhour Array don't have a fixed number of entries. 
Sometime it can be 5, 10, 14 and other time just 14,20 etc

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I got your idea. Do you need to find the nearest number to currenthour from myhour array?

That's it:

```
var minDiff : int = 12;
var diff : int;
var index : int = 0;   

for (var i : int = 0; i < myhour.length; i++)
{
    diff = Math.abs(myhour[i] - currenthour);
    if (diff > 12)
        diff = 24 - diff;
    if (diff < minDiff)
    {
        minDiff = diff;
        index = i;
    }
}
```

`myhour[index]` is the result. Hope, I got an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your numbers on a line, from 0 to 24. 
Using a variable to keep track of the smallest distance between the current hours and each hour in your XML, you can find the index of the node you're looking for:

```
import mx.xpath.XPathAPI;

var myxml:XML = new XML();
myxml.ignoreWhite = true;
myxml.onLoad = function(loaded:Boolean) {
    if (loaded) {
        var hoursMin:Number = 24;
        var hoursNow:Number = new Date().getUTCHours();
        var hourID:Number;
        var hours:Array = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(this.firstChild, "xml/prevision/hour");
        var hoursNum:Number = hours.length;
        for(var i:Number = 0 ; i < hoursNum; i++){
            var hoursDiff:Number = Math.abs(hoursNow - parseInt(hours[i].firstChild));//look for the 'shortest distance' within 24 numbers
            if(hoursDiff < hoursMin){//found the smallest current value
                hoursMin = hoursDiff;//update the minimum
                hourID = i;//store the node ID
            }
        }
        trace(this.firstChild.childNodes[hourID]);//access the closest node in time
    } else {
        trace("XML Load Error!!");
    }
}
myxml.load("feed.xml");
```

Here's the same thing without XPath, although I find accessing nodes a bit harder this way:

```
var myxml:XML = new XML();
myxml.ignoreWhite = true;
myxml.onLoad = function(loaded:Boolean) {
    if (loaded) {
        var hoursMin:Number = 24;
        var hoursNow:Number = new Date().getUTCHours();
        var hourID:Number;
        var hoursNum:Number = this.firstChild.childNodes.length;
        for(var i:Number = 0 ; i < hoursNum; i++){
            var hoursDiff:Number = Math.abs(hoursNow - parseInt(this.firstChild.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].firstChild));//look for the 'shortest distance' within 24 numbers
            if(hoursDiff < hoursMin){//found the smallest current value
                hoursMin = hoursDiff;//update the minimum
                hourID = i;//store the node ID
            }
        }
        trace(this.firstChild.childNodes[hourID]);//access the closest node in time
    } else {
        trace("XML Load Error!!");
    }
}
myxml.load("feed.xml");
```

HTH